# Set maximum width of labels in an ASP.NET Chart

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, charts, mschart

I am using the .NET 4 Chart control to create a bar chart. I have labels listed along the left axis (I believe this is the y-axis, I may be wrong). I want to set the maximum width that this axis can be. Currently, I have some labels that are really large. Ideally, I would like to truncate them. However, I cannot figure out how to do either of these.

Can someone tell me how to set the maximum width used by the labels in a Chart? Is it possible to truncate the labels so that if they are larger than the alloted space a "..." appears?

Thank you

Comment: I have tinkered with this and despite several properties existing (i.e. chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.TruncatedLabels, chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MaximumAutoSize, etc etc) I could not get any of them to work. I recommend writing a function that measures string width, or if a rough approximation is good enough, just counts characters and truncates/adds an ellipsis.  This 'simple' solution would work if the size of your plot is static and if you are using the datapoint.AxisLabel property to set your Y-Labels.  I will report back a real answer if I can get this control to behave!

Answer (score 0):

I think below code helps to truncate x-axis width. check out something similar to this. 
Chart1.Series("Series1")("PixelPointWidth") = "35"